# Rails rookie - is there a simpler way to write this link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying out my first website in rails and i'm trying to creating a link that ultimately looks like this:

```
<a href="home_controller"><span>Home</span></a>
```

This produces my desired output, but is there a more refactored way to write this?

```
<%= link_to :controller => "home" do %>
    <span>Home</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean the only other way you could do it would be as follows:

```
<%= link_to raw('<span>Home</span>'), controller: 'home' %>
```

but I'm not sure that is any better, short isn't any better, and I think your solution is really the best, most clear way to express your intent.

Comment: Good to know. I was not aware of the raw function and I wasn't sure if `:controller => "controllerName"` was the best way to link to another controller either.

Comment: Well you also need an action, I thought it was just pseduo code.  Accept my answer and upvote me then please if your happy! :)

Comment: Will do. I was just waiting to see if anyone else had any input. I'm sure you'll be hearing from me alot in the next couple of days.